# how to create tree list view in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, treeview

how to create a menu tree list view in android studio?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFUjZ.jpg]

**I need video tutorial how to build it**!

Comment: I think you got the wrong site. I suggest Youtube for video tutorials

Comment: I did not find YouTube

Answer (score 0):

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.dhanya.listview.MainActivity">
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listv">
    </ListView>
</android.widget.LinearLayout>
```

main_activity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    ListView lv;
    String days[]={"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv=findViewById(R.id.listv);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ada=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,days);
        lv.setAdapter(ada);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) view;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "u have selected" + txt.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question?